# How do I find the critical points of this function?

Tags: calculus

My online homework question reads: 
Let $f(x) = (x - 3)^3 + (x - 3)^{-3}$.

I set up to find the critical points by first finding the derivative of the equation. I used the power rule at first and got $3(x-3)^2-\frac{3}{(x-3)^4}$. Then I was attempting to use the power rule, however, I think I am going about the problem all wrong. 
Any assistance on how to find the critical points for the equation would be helpful! Thank you

Comment: Good start.  Setting your derivative to $0$ gives you two critical points.  Don't forget, though, that you should also include points where the derivative is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Set the first derivative equal to zero:

$$0 = 3(x-2)^2 - \frac{3}{(x-3)^4}$$
$$(x-3)^6 = 1 \to x = 4, 2$$

Then continue from there.

Answer (score -1):

the critical points $f'(x)=3(x-3)^2-\frac{3}{(x-3)^4}=0$

$3(x-3)^2=\frac{3}{(x-3)^4}$

$(x-3)^6=1$

$x=3$

Or [graphically](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=3%28x-3%29%5E2,3+/%28x-3%5E4%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=y-w4Vs29JMyqjwPH44-gCQ)

Comment: The solutions to $(x-3)^6=1$ are $x=2,4$.

Comment: As lulu already mentioned. $x=3$ is not a solution to the equation $$(x-3)^6=1$$
You should fix that.